# Create data frame with 101 columns named 0 to 1 with interval of 0.01

Tags: pandas

I am using the below code to create data frame with 101 columns named 0 to 1 with interval of 0.01 but certain columns are having bizarre values as shown further. How to get columns names with only two decimal points

```
    time_points = numpy.arange(0, 1.01, 0.01)
    
    # Create a list of dictionaries with product and attribute values as keys and 0 as the default value for each time point
    data = []
    row = {
                **{float(time_point): 0 for time_point in time_points}
            }
    
    data.append(row)
    
    # Create the DataFrame from the list of dictionaries
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df
    
    df.columns[40:50]

Index([                0.4, 0.41000000000000003,                0.42,
                      0.43,                0.44,                0.45,
                      0.46, 0.47000000000000003,                0.48,
                      0.49],
      dtype='float64')
```

Comment: `time_points = np.arange(0, 1.01, 0.01).round(2)`